# Step Function Proofs

Tags: integration, step-function

My notes give a lemma but I,m snuggling how the lemma actually works. Any help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: $f \leq g$ implies $\int f \leq \int g $

Answer (score 2):

From $0 \le f(x) \le \frac{\lambda}{b-a}$ it follows that

$$0 = \int_a^b 0 dx \le \int_a^b f(x) dx \le \int_a^b\frac{\lambda}{b-a}= \lambda .$$